# How can I prevent the transaction log from growing indefinitely when deleting lots of rows?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, sql-delete

I am using a loop to delete many rows in chunks.

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table WHERE LogTime < CAST('2018-11-05' AS 
  DATE))
  BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION T1
        DELETE TOP (1000) FROM dbo.Table 
        WHERE LogTime < CAST('2018-11-05' AS date);
    COMMIT;
END
```

I expect that each While Loop Cycle is one transaction which ends with "COMMIT" and therefore that the transaction log is being cleaned after every loop cycle.

Unfortunately this is not the case. At some point after like 15 Minutes the query crashes because of "transaction log is full". Then a rollback is started which rollsback not only the last loop cycle, but the whole query including all the other loop cycles.

Comment: That's not how the log works. In the FULL mode, the log records remain until the log gets backed up. If a crash rolls everything back it means you have *another* overall transaction, so nothing would be deleted even in the SIMPLE mode. SQL Server doesn't have nested transactions so the outer one is the only one that matters. Commiting the inner transaction doesn't do anything. A ROLLBACK would roll back everything

Comment: If you have frequent batch deletes you should use table partitioning and just truncate the unwanted partitions with `TRUNCATE TABLE Imagination_Partitioned WITH (PARTITIONS(@partition))`. Partitions are available in all editions (even Express) since SQL Server 2016 SP1 and given that 2016 is the oldest supported version, all supported versions

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos! Is it possible to add Table Partitions afterwards when there is already a lot of data in the table? Could I create a partition per Month and Year?

Comment: The article [How to Partition SQL Server Tables and Truncate Partitions](https://stackify.com/how-to-partition-tables-in-azure-sql/) explains partitioning and contains an interesting example, including a method that calculates which partitions to truncate based on the date

Comment: You can create partitions after the fact although it's going to take a while as the data gets moved around. The partitioning scheme depends on *your* requirements - how many rows are there, how much data do you want to remove and how often? You can also switch partitions between tables with identical schemas (it's just a metadata operation and almost instantaneous), which means you could move data to a History table before truncating partitions

Comment: And as far as I read, Table Partitioning is only available in SQL Server Enterprise, which we are not using

Comment: You didn't read my comment then. No, that's not true. In fact, it's 100% false for supported editions. `Partitions are available in all editions (even Express) since SQL Server 2016 SP1 and given that 2016 is the oldest supported version, all supported versions ` Other features available everywhere are "exotics" like columnstore indexes, compression and in-memory tables. You may not need to delete any data, just compress it or use a columnstore

Comment: Check [A Big Deal : SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 1](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/11/sql-server-2016/big-deal-sp1)

Comment: We are using SQL Server 2012 - that explains why it's not available for use.

Comment: Wouldn't it also be an option to set the "Recovery Mode" to Simple instead of Full?

Comment: And lose every change since the last full backup? Only if you can reproduce that data, eg by reloading them. That may be appropriate for a reporting database, probably not for an OLTP database. FULL allows you to take frequent small transaction log backups that allow you to restore the database to a point very close to the point of failure. If you take eg a weekly full, daily diff backup, you can take transaction log backups every hour or 15 minutes to allow you to get back to the last 1 hour or 15 minutes (or whatever) before a failure

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, these comments should be the answer, so I can upvote them.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand. In our case we are storing log data in the database, which we can always reimport from the original log files. Therefore it is not critical at all to be able to do a restore for a specific point in time. So I assume that recovery mode "simple" is our choice in this case. Once we get the chance to upgrade to a newer version of SQL Server we will consider using partitions.

Comment: @ThomasHahn that upgrade is long overdue. SQL Server 2012 is already out of mainstream support since 2017, and that's for SP4. Even SQL Server 2014 went out of mainstream support recently. You can still *pay* Microsoft for fixes per incident, but you'll be paying for stuff already fixed in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by setting the recovery mode of the database to "Simple" instead of "Full". This makes sure that the transaction log does not grow indefinitely. But you have to be careful: this will not be an option for all sorts of databases. In our case, we are storing log information, which can easily be reimported if there was data loss. But for production databases, you should use the "Full" recovery mode and rather work with table partitions.